# Dropdown menu that drops when clicking

Tags: html, css

I am not intending to use jquery/javascript. Html/css/php only!
I want a dropdown menu to drop down when clicked on and to go away when clicked somewhere else.
How would i do this with `:target` in css?/Is it possible?
How would i do this with `onclick`-attribute?/Is it possible?
What would be a different method, not using jquery?
Example Code: https://jsfiddle.net/kf42qc2h/

Comment: Why can't you use `<select>`?

Comment: First of all, PHP has nothing to do here - it's server side language. Second - using `onclick` means using JavaScript.

Comment: cant i change css style like `display: block;` with onclick?

Comment: Take a look at this, might help you: https://jsfiddle.net/Cerebrl/uhykY/

Comment: `.target` or the checkbox hack are the two main techniques, if you want to limit it to HTML & CSS only. `onclick` of course would be JavaScript again.

Answer (score 0):

By using onclick function you can do. but inside onclick what we written that is called inline javascript like inline css

like this....

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    li ul{display:none;}
</style>

<ul class="parent">
    <li onclick="$('.child').hide();$(this).find('.child').show();">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <ul class="child">
            <li>Home1</li>
            <li>Home2</li>
            <li>Home3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li  onclick="$('.child').hide();$(this).find('.child').show();">
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <ul class="child">
            <li>About1</li>
            <li>About2</li>
            <li>About3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```